# How to modify database structure on sold web applications (PHP & MySQL) as a patch?

Tags: php, mysql, web-applications, updates, patch

I've created a web application using PHP and MySQL that customers can buy it and install on their servers. It has a database installer script that setup tables and predefined data. Up to now, everything is OK.  But I might need to apply some changes on database structure for newer features and versions. On the other hand, I have not access to their servers, and also I can not ask them to apply these changes manually by themselves. So I need to do it using an script through update files.
How can I do it transparently because I don't like customers know anything about it? Other updates will apply just replacing files with newer one. But what about database? Also I need to do these changes only once.

What is the best way to do that?

Comment: Doing something secretly doesn't make it transparent

Comment: You know @Dale, transparency is not very important in this case. I actually need to do database updates without customers manual actions. I want to ask them to replace update files (like WHMCS)

Comment: Then what is stopping you from writing alter table sql in those scripts?
Like ask them to replace files and go to "webapp.com/tool/update.php
Or add some code on login that compares version stored in database to the one in the update files - and runs a update.php script if it's different.
Ajax, js, php - so the user gets some feedback like " Updating files ... , Updating database".

Comment: @MauroTamm, I'm seeking the best method. I thought to your solutions too. It's good. Just I wanted to make sure it is a correct way.

Comment: The only way to run a db update like that without user manually doing anything is to run it the next time the webapp is launched.
For that you need a way to identify a pending update.
Can also be a function that checks for a update file - if it exists, it will redirect to the update.php. Once successfully finished - delete it.